# Disk size is larger than image size when creating Compute Engine VM in Google Cloud Deployment Manager Template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using a Google Cloud Deployment Manager Template to create a Compute Engine VM instance in Google Cloud. However, I'm encountering a warning during the deployment process: *"Disk size: '60 GB' is larger than image size: '10 GB'*." The deployment is completed successfully, but I want to understand the implications of this warning and how to address it.

**Here is my Deployment Manager template code:**

```py
def generate_config(context):
    COMPUTE_URL_BASE = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects"
    SOURCE_IMAGE=f"{COMPUTE_URL_BASE}/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-11"
    DISK_SIZE=60
    
    VM_MACHINE_TYPE = "g1-small"
    REGION = "europe-west2-b"
    PROJECT_ID = context.env["project"]
    VPC_NETWORK="default"
    SUBNETWORK="default"


    VM = {
        "name": "dinesh-vm",
        "type": "compute.v1.instance",
        "properties": {
            "zone": REGION,
            "machineType": f"zones/{REGION}/machineTypes/{VM_MACHINE_TYPE}",
            "disks": [{
                "boot": True,
                "autoDelete": True,
                "initializeParams": {
                    "sourceImage": SOURCE_IMAGE,
                    "diskSizeGb": DISK_SIZE,
                },
            }],
            "networkInterfaces": [{
                "network": f"{COMPUTE_URL_BASE}/{PROJECT_ID}/global/networks/{VPC_NETWORK}",
                "subnetwork": f"{COMPUTE_URL_BASE}/{PROJECT_ID}/regions/europe-west2/subnetworks/{SUBNETWORK}",
                "accessConfigs": [{
                    "name": "External NAT",
                    "networkTier": "PREMIUM",
                    "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
                }],
            }]
        }
    }
    return {"resources": [VM]}
```

**During the deployment process, I receive the following warning:**

```
dineshsonachalam@macbook compute_engine % gcloud deployment-manager deployments create dinesh-vm --template vm.py
The fingerprint of the deployment is b'ZmY2S4OqjswQhQfT_=='
Waiting for create [operation-1684]...done.                                                                       
WARNING: Create operation operation-1674932237 completed with warnings:
---
code: EXTERNAL_API_WARNING
data:
- key: disk_size_gb
  value: '60'
- key: image_size_gb
  value: '10'
message: "Disk size: '60 GB' is larger than image size: '10 GB'. You might need to\
  \ resize the root repartition manually if the operating system does not support\
  \ automatic resizing. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd\
  \ for details."

NAME       TYPE                 STATE      ERRORS  INTENT
dinesh-vm  compute.v1.instance  COMPLETED  []
dineshsonachalam@macbook compute_engine %
```

I would like to understand the implications of this warning and how I can address it.
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**

It seems like if you're using a public image, Compute Engine automatically resizes the boot disks.

```
dineshsonachalam@macbook Desktop % gcloud compute images list | grep -i "debian"
NAME                                                  PROJECT              FAMILY                             DEPRECATED  STATUS
debian-10-buster-v20230510                            debian-cloud         debian-10                                      READY
debian-11-bullseye-v20230509                          debian-cloud         debian-11                                      READY
```

[image]
**Reference:** https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk

If automatic resizing is supported, why am I still receiving the warning?

Comment: This is just a warning and we can ignore it as per your discretion.


If you create a disk larger than the size of the image in GCP, the usable space will only be equal to the size of the image. For example, if you create a disk of 30GB using one of the default images in GCP, which has a size of 10GB, the usable space will still only be 10GB. 


By following this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk) you can resize the disk size.

Comment: Most likely you have no problem. The Debian images support automatic resizing of the root file system. I wrote an article about this with tips to figure out what you have and verify that the resize happened. https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Answer (score 2):

This is just a warning and we can ignore it as per your discretion. If you create a disk larger than the size of the image in GCP, the usable space will only be equal to the size of the image. For example, if you create a disk of 30GB using one of the default images in GCP, which has a size of 10GB, the usable space will still only be 10GB. By following this [official doc1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk) and [Doc2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize) you can resize the disk size. To avoid the warning, you can revise your template to use disk size >= 200GB

> As  per @Johnhanley comments The Debian images support automatic
> resizing of the root file system. You can Go through the [blog](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/) By
> John Hanley on October 27th, 2018 in Debian, Google